# Getting results of nearby places from User's Location using Google Maps API in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-places-api

This is the first time using google map API and google places API. I am doing a demo application that displays the list hospitals (for example) nearest to the user's location with routes to each of the hospitals. I been able to get the user's location with the code below the:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private GoogleMap map;
    UiSettings mapSettings;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        if (map != null) {
           // map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(myLocation).title("Start"));
            map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mapSettings = map.getUiSettings();
            mapSettings.setScrollGesturesEnabled(true);
            mapSettings.setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        }
    }
}
```

The xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

My question how do I get the list of hospitals using google places API and display them. Any help,tips,walkthrough or tutorials will really be appericaited.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: [Nearby Place](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/) for Android, bro. Hope this help ^^

Comment: Infact this would help...https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/
if someone is looking for json out and not want to include maps in their apps

Answer (score 24):

For Android, I tried to use `Place picker for Android`. It can add the `built-in place picker UI widget` to your app, so users can choose from a set of nearby places displayed on a map. It easy to use, you just need to do is:

```
int PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST = 1;
PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();    
startActivityForResult(builder.build(this), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
```

It will show the UI below to pick a place for you, and you can get the place info by using below:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, this);
        String toastMsg = String.format("Place: %s", place.getName());
        Toast.makeText(this, toastMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

For more details, please refer to guide [here](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/placepicker) and code [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-places/blob/master/PlacePicker/Application/src/main/java/com/example/google/playservices/placepicker/PlacePickerFragment.java#L106-L170).

However, it cannot set the place type because it no feature for the Build in UI.. If you really need to set, you should use `Google Places API Web Service API` [here](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests), search the location yourself, parse the JSON data, and show on your own UI.

A Nearby Search lets you search for places within a specified area. You can refine your search request by supplying keywords or specifying the type of place you are searching for.

A Nearby Search request is an HTTP URL of the following form:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/output?parameters
```

Note that in parameters you need to set `types=hospital`

**EDIT**

Example on how to pass the search request for specific locations in JSON using the google places API web API web service API.

Request

```
location: -33.8670,151.1957
radius: 500
types: food
name: cruise
key: API_KEY
```

Url for this:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670,151.1957&radius=500&types=food&name=cruise&key=API_KEY

and Response JSON like this:

```
{
   "debug_log" : {
      "line" : []
   },
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "logging_info" : {
      "experiment_id" : [],
      "query_geographic_location" : "AU"
   },
   "results" : [
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -33.86879,
               "lng" : 151.194217
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
         "id" : "21a0b251c9b8392186142c798263e289fe45b4aa",
         "name" : "Rhythmboat Cruises",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : false,
            "weekday_text" : []
         },
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 426,
               "html_attributions" : [
                  "\u003ca href=\"https://www.google.com/maps/views/profile/104066891898402903288\"\u003eRhythmboat Cruises\u003c/a\u003e"
               ],
               "photo_reference" : "CmRdAAAA-YL_I_Gk02blOX6S0nKHry8PFu9pDyp3Y9AnqISsa3Eq8mkbdD5mXuu1Fax60s0nSy3iiX-h5j-ztyLHcc1-782MsLQsgLLa4t3ZgDmCMll-a8ABapZGnZwDKByk67LFEhBgedv_u_eYFsEo9ay8jxJjGhTUHKPJ4G82vBJqSNliuv7UlAtclw",
               "width" : 640
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJyWEHuEmuEmsRm9hTkapTCrk",
         "reference" : "CnRmAAAAvQlMKw-XtxEY4vWFCvudF7CEMQGI5ycNbfVgGl9rAF75fdiPOiLJw1k9NL2v8ZIJsOJuRS3Lm9Dw1vga4ajycAs7PlxN1MVnnYT9la0pBvEvSQNlyvszKANS1R4P7Mvk_jhqswMggqCUtwJ13LN2hRIQOiAkLTWUi3DOjVVOw7J5IRoUb_cJyJaJNqKdmkDM2f0OjQjh9F0",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "restaurant", "food", "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "Pyrmont Bay Wharf (Near Australia Maritime Museum), Pyrmont, NSW 2009"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -33.867591,
               "lng" : 151.201196
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
         "id" : "a97f9fb468bcd26b68a23072a55af82d4b325e0d",
         "name" : "Australian Cruise Group",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : false,
            "weekday_text" : []
         },
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 1331,
               "html_attributions" : [
                  "\u003ca href=\"https://www.google.com/maps/views/profile/110751364053842618118\"\u003eAustralian Cruise Group\u003c/a\u003e"
               ],
               "photo_reference" : "CmRdAAAAtEoj29FJcNBccrsu6bHt0xgwVGhYlciCY1fe6gTr_d5_KkeP3LITnOwnpNRJWnX39B04-aIBOKXKJH6ltx948T5vWIYBoah1yZDXsWngWZ5kMsK7xyCB5P_q_xBIBxxUEhAYWeB4PiOm_Jy093fB-j0iGhSYmIs9xB2aa6u-RH8V8lZEk-Q5ig",
               "width" : 2000
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJrTLr-GyuEmsRBfy61i59si0",
         "reference" : "CnRqAAAAFbukrZvRNsc05TreHUCrPEya5NcN9v0fFLLaK-D1fSyxFTuQlUDhDstU3qwXKw_fADX4W6guUkexax1nufgiYIuGCKoZPEnup1r-LhGGNz9dn1uf9Of5iOtZ1XgCeDjJaYvGbSB3C0pAXL8r9kOsmhIQbx2Sia2DAWTjtSZwuh5aehoUhM6upqBCDLhGruZAGGsCOwAiIq8",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [
            "restaurant",
            "travel_agency",
            "food",
            "point_of_interest",
            "establishment"
         ],
         "vicinity" : "32 The Promenade, King Street Wharf 5, Sydney"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -33.870943,
               "lng" : 151.190311
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/bar-71.png",
         "id" : "e644f7f34cf875b9919c6548f1b721947362850a",
         "name" : "Lunch Cruise with Jazz on Sydney Harbour",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : false,
            "weekday_text" : []
         },
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 292,
               "html_attributions" : [
                  "\u003ca href=\"https://www.google.com/maps/views/profile/105423912060796272053\"\u003eFrom a Google User\u003c/a\u003e"
               ],
               "photo_reference" : "CmRdAAAAR4bqFTKYWdBwZwdBdON_JRD7V_joTwwIPwRUpZIZWkSSd8GQ3P2O-_aQbUJdL2RhoAyzCUIF0f--DI4oXFneTpj5zZfFq-iFiT7i_x0tjnDveIY8tJv-6o0uWSSjYqabEhCKqQWZqrKAoddjDcc64N48GhQZ2T1_ntPzNKCooHpZzlYQ7AxFOA",
               "width" : 438
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJLfySpTOuEmsRPCRKrzl8ZEY",
         "reference" : "CoQBewAAAFd2fO_YWGTiT4RzXWb5tsOuOt7YyV_ScQOwm0tqJSrAyACCczeOzV-P_mgZLro1oKP_34Nt0nVC_1OEKAQUcd7cUm7xmAMSX-EkbSWiD0kOWGgGgKuDRtb0t_8qsxBGU_izugWCyK7SRWezTxELYNdkS0OEiSWPnvhxvXuQktBBEhAAtEe7fagW2kUR14T1QpVsGhQBO7YpIyYSPvo4zUJuL_bX30nJZw",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "bar", "restaurant", "food", "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "37 Bank St, Pyrmont"
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

The below example returns a list of hospitals near London, England.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=51.503186,-0.126446&radius=5000&types=hospital&key=API_KEY
```

For more details please refer [here](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/).

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for. Can you please give me an example on how to pass the search request for specific locations in JSON using the google places API web API web service API? Because I need the search to be static (i.e it will constantly be search one place e.g cinemas based on the users location)Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Sorry for delay reply, I am on vacation BTW:) Please see the edit in my answer.

Comment: which api key will be pass in the link are you talking about Google Place API?

Comment: @AhmadArslan https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/get-api-key

Comment: Unfortunately web API https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/output?parameters is billable now and fetching place details will cost a lot. As a developer you get 200$ credit per month, but if you publish an android application with thousands of downloads, bills are huge, thousand of dollars per month. Android application that are published only possibility is use native Android Places API, where quotas are what they previously were in places Web API.

Comment: @bjiang its working properly but sometimes i got this error
You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API. If you did not set a custom daily request quota, verify your project has an active billing account: http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account
then again refresh it works..
what is the issue?

Answer (score 3):

Follow this link, it has all explained out,

in the String type='grocery_or_supermarket' replace it to be 'hospital' and you'll be good to go:

http://androidmastermind.blogspot.co.ke/2016/06/android-google-maps-with-nearyby-places.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing a quote or necessary data to back up your claims: `String type='grocery[…]`. See this reference: http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing

Answer (score 1):

```
 private void loadNearByPlaces(double latitude, double longitude)

//YOU Can change this type at your own will, e.g hospital, cafe, restaurant.... and see how it all works
{


    mMap.clear();
    Intent i = getIntent();
    String type = hospital;

    StringBuilder googlePlacesUrl =
            new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
    googlePlacesUrl.append("location=").append(latitude).append(",").append(longitude);
    googlePlacesUrl.append("&radius=").append(PROXIMITY_RADIUS);
    googlePlacesUrl.append("&types=").append(type);
    googlePlacesUrl.append("&sensor=true");
    googlePlacesUrl.append("&key=" + GOOGLE_BROWSER_API_KEY);

    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(googlePlacesUrl.toString(),
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject result) {

                    Log.i(TAG, "onResponse: Result= " + result.toString());
                    parseLocationResult(result);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onErrorResponse: Error= " + error);
                    Log.e(TAG, "onErrorResponse: Error= " + error.getMessage());
                }
            });

    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);
}
```

This will load the near by hospital according to your location.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below code:

```
private static final String TAG_RESULT = "predictions";
JSONObject json;


ArrayList<String> names;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
String browserKey = "Google API key";
//------------------------AutoComplete code--------------  
  public void updateList(String place) {
        String input = "";

        try {
            input = "input=" + URLEncoder.encode(place, "utf-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        String output = "json";
        String parameter = input + "&types=geocode&sensor=true&key="                + browserKey;

        url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/"                + output + "?" + parameter;

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                System.out.println("response"+response);
                try {

                    JSONArray ja = response.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULT);

                    for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = ja.getJSONObject(i);
                        String description = c.getString("description");
                        System.out.println("description"+description);
                        names.add(description);
                    }

                    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names) {
                        @Override                        public View getView(int position,
                                            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                            View view = super.getView(position,
                                    convertView, parent);
                            TextView text = (TextView) view
                                    .findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                            text.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                            return view;
                        }
                    };
                    edittext_signup_city.setAdapter(adapter);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            }
        });
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq, "jreq");
    }
```