# How To Call An Intent to Select a place with the help of Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I am making an app and in the user profile page I need to set up something like, a user can start typing the location and a new Google Maps intent is called. As user types the place name it will start listing out suggestions and when user selects one, he/she can see a piece of map in the profile page.

I have referred the latest Lollipop Google Calendar create event screen and it has similar implementation. Please refer the below screenshots;

To keep it simple, my requirement is

1. The screen has a `EditText` which on typing will load a list of suggestions. This is loading from the Google maps database.
2. Once the user select one of the option from the list, `EditText` name should change to the selected one and then below that the piece of map view should also be shown.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use URI fragment to fetch the location from google map

for Example:

[find example here](http://%20%20Uri%20gmmIntentUri%20=%20Uri.parse(%22google.navigation:q=Taronga+Zoo,+Sydney+Australia&mode=b%22);%20Intent%20mapIntent%20=%20new%20Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,%20gmmIntentUri);%20mapIntent.setPackage(%22com.google.android.apps.maps%22);%20startActivity(mapIntent);)

you can use geolocation geocoding to fetch the location

use this [link](http://javapapers.com/android/android-get-address-with-street-name-city-for-location-with-geocoding/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32393134/getting-results-of-nearby-places-from-users-location-using-google-maps-api-in-a