# Android - Getting nearby cities around a location

Tags: android, google-maps, location, city

After a lot of researchs in Stack I havn't been able to find a correct answer.

My problem is this: I want to get a string array with the city names surrounding user's location for a given radius.

I already retrieved user's location with `LocationManager` and user's city with `Geocoder`

Any answer of the already asked ones in this page has given to me a satisfactory way to achieve this.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: please take a look on this  question :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32393134/getting-results-of-nearby-places-from-users-location-using-google-maps-api-in-a ,you will get an idea about it

Comment: I said that I took a look to all this questions. The problem is that people need places around him but anyone is looking for cities around, and retrieving places around is quite easy whereas retrieving cities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by using GeoFire. It works fine and it's pretty easy to use I recommend it !

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is no such functionality in Google Maps APIs.

There was a feature request in the public issue tracker

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4374

However, Google marked it as Won't Fix.