# Google Maps API for location of a specific store

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, google-api

How can I locate all Walmart store(or any specific store, Walmart is just an example) near my location in my Android application? Which google API shall I use?

Comment: Please check this out url 
   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32393134/getting-results-of-nearby-places-from-users-location-using-google-maps-api-in-a

Comment: Place picker is more generic to all the nearby hospitals. But what if I just want all the Starbucks near my location instead of all coffee shops near my location?

Comment: Check below url there i've added name Dominos and see result.
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670,151.1957&radius=500&types=food&name=dominos&key=

Comment: @bharat7777 the link doesn't work because of the API authentication

Comment: You need to use GOOGLE API KEY for executing.

Comment: I used google API Key  but it gives me this error: {
   "error_message" : "This API project is not authorized to use this API. Please ensure this API is activated in the Google Developers Console: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/places_backend?project=_",
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search) or the [Android specific page](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/)