# How to get near by TEMPLE Event details using Google API?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, google-nearby

is it possible to get all the near by TEMPLE Event details in Google API ? i can use near by places API to get the near by Temple but don't know how to get the event details in same API ?

Comment: check out link below ,hope this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32393134/getting-results-of-nearby-places-from-users-location-using-google-maps-api-in-a

Comment: @Ashish  , i can get those details but  what about the Events (Festival)details ,how i will get those details .